# How can I upload binaries on n Arduino UNO R3?

Tags: arduino, upload, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno and I would like to upload a `.bin` file.

I have found an answer on Google which recommends that I use IAR to upload the binary, but my PC has very low memory.

I have tried doing it via terminal

```sh
sudo cp ./blinky.bin /media/edwin/UNO/
```

But I'm getting an odd error saying that the board is not found.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out that on Linux, we have to *mount* media devices before we can send files to them.

I used

```sh
sudo mount /media/Edwin/UNO/
```

And I have found that if we open the device in the file manager, it mounts automatically.

In terms of copying, I found that we could also drag a file to the destination in the file manager.

This makes it soo easy!